# Not Feeling Confident In My New Position - Should I Return To My Old Position?

Tags: promotion, teamleader

It's been about 8 weeks at the new position I've been promoted to at my office, and while I would have hoped to feel more confident in this position by now, I'm not feeling as confident as I would like.

In my old position, I was responsible for managing a small application group that, primarily, dealt with one legacy application that would receive updates every 3 months or so.  We didn't have to manage Soap or Rest, we had one dedicated SQL guy, and application changes were primarily just Java code.  My supervisory tasks were almost non-existent.

Now I've been promoted to a team lead, and the challenges that are facing me are daunting.  I have to learn the structure of the SQL packaging, learn how to test in SoapUI, learn how to manage XML Requests (one of the few things that seem straightforward), and have to learn to manage a much larger network of applications.

The former team lead is guiding me, but the amount of information he's trying to pour out in every Knowledge Transfer make it hard for me to break apart what is actually important to learn. He's also an extremely hands-on Team Lead, and expects me to be the same despite not having as well developed a skill pool as him *or* as deep an understanding of the applications he supports.

I'm afraid it might be months before I even feel confident in managing this team, let alone assisting with any of the daily processes that get distributed to them. I was hoping to learn more about modern application processes when our old team started upgrading to a new system, but now it feels like I have to learn all of that at once and am completely unprepared for the challenge.

Is my concern here warranted? Or am I panicking over nothing?

Comment: As phrased, this is on the edge of "we can't make that decision for you", but since impostor syndrome is so common I think a general answer is valuable.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It hasn't been filled out yet.

Comment: Can you document everything the former team lead teach you ? You can write that down, and refer back to it whenever you need it for your work.  Hopefully, that will make your job easier.

Comment: The things you are struggling don't seem to be specifically about being a team lead but more to be the pains of switching a team.

Comment: As team lead you don't have time to know the technical details of everything - rather you need to make sure the team as a whole has the required knowledge (and you can learn from them over time). It sounds like the previous lead has done you no favours by hoarding that knowledge, and perhaps being hands on at the expense of actually leading?

Answer (score 3):

Eight weeks isn't enough time to spend before taking any drastic measures.

Trying to go back to your old position would likely signal that you aren't able to be promoted again. That could mean you are at a dead end with this company.

Not everyone is suited to be a team lead. Not everyone can handle a larger network of applications. But you owe it to yourself to at least give it a good shot.

Unless your boss is indicating that you are coming up to speed too slowly, just work hard, take your time, and do your best.

Answer (score 1):

You're learning/improving a new set of skills. Give yourself time to do so, and to start feeling comfortable with them, asking for guidance as needed.

On the other hand, it it just isn't clicking there's no shame in telling management that you think you need some education before you'll be comfortable in this role.

And it isn't absolutely necessary, in some companies, to take a formal team leadership role to advance -- but make sure you're stepping up into technical leadership in that case, getting involved in higher-level decisions, generating intellectual property such as patent applications, and generally working toward being the person folks cone to for advice and creative solutions to difficult questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a rule of thumb that to become 'competent' in a new role/business takes at least 3-6 months.

What I mean by that is if you go from being a dedicated SQL engineer from Company A to Company B - it will take you this amount of time to learn how Company B does things, the majority of skeletons in the closets, all those little details that make it unique from Company A and that takes time.

Now, for a new role in a company, whilst you may know all those company details - the new Role has it's own 'way of doing things' and it's own 'Skeletons' and other nuances that again takes time to learn.

Right now - you are trying to drink from a Firehose - and it's tough, We've all been there in some way shape or form and it feels like you are drowning.

**This too, shall pass**

Give it at least 3 months, that should be when things start to settle and you start to get a handle on what is important and what isn't and start making judgement calls, then after 6 months - you should be kicking ass and taking names.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you start by leading the team, rather than trying to immediately learn every technology that the team uses.

Ultimately, you only have to know enough that you can allocate tasks to the right people, and evaluate when a task has been finished correctly.  You don't have to know everything about what the team member does to finish the task.

Encourage team members to discuss problems with each other and with anyone else in the company who has specialist knowledge, rather than you being the source of all knowledge.